# how to get the same result as librosa stft with numpy (or vice versa)?

Tags: python, numpy, fft, librosa

so i have

```
signal = np.array([0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9])
frame_length_ex = 4
hop_length_ex = 2
```

and when i tried using librosa.stft

```
apply_stft_ex = librosa.stft(np.transpose(signal), n_fft=frame_length_ex, hop_length=hop_length_ex, window='hamming', center=False
```

i got

```
array([[ 0.416+0.j   ,  0.848+0.j   ,  1.28 +0.j   ,  1.712+0.j   ],
       [-0.2  +0.108j, -0.384+0.108j, -0.568+0.108j, -0.752+0.108j],
       [-0.016+0.j   , -0.016+0.j   , -0.016+0.j   , -0.016+0.j   ]])
```

while using numpy with this code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def stft(signal, window_size, hop_size, window_function=np.hamming):
    signal_length = len(signal)
    num_frames = int(np.ceil((signal_length - window_size) / hop_size)) + 1
    padded_signal = np.pad(signal, (0, num_frames * hop_size + window_size - signal_length), mode='constant')
    stft_matrix = np.zeros((window_size, num_frames), dtype=complex)

    window = window_function(window_size)

    for i in range(num_frames):
        start = i * hop_size
        end = start + window_size
        segment = padded_signal[start:end]
        windowed_segment = segment * window
        stft_matrix[:, i] = np.fft.fft(windowed_segment)

    return stft_matrix, windowed_segment

# Example usage
signal = np.array([0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9])
window_size = 4
hop_size = 2

result, windowed = stft(signal, window_size, hop_size)
```

i got

```
array([[ 0.255+0.j   ,  0.595+0.j   ,  0.935+0.j   ,  1.275+0.j   ],
       [-0.154-0.053j, -0.292-0.191j, -0.43 -0.329j, -0.568-0.467j],
       [ 0.053+0.j   ,  0.053+0.j   ,  0.053+0.j   ,  0.053+0.j   ],
       [-0.154+0.053j, -0.292+0.191j, -0.43 +0.329j, -0.568+0.467j]])
```

why is the result different ? i don't really understand how stft or fft works so i'm lost here